# DBIx::Class: sub resultset in Template Toolkit presented as an array, not a resultset

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class, template-toolkit

I am developing a Catalyst application using DBIx::Class and Template Toolkit; in the particular part I'm having issues with, I have a resultset obtained using by calling the following function in my ResultSet schema:

```
    sub divisions_and_teams_in_season {
      my ( $self, $season, $grid ) = @_;

      return $self->search({
          "division_seasons.season"         => $season->id,
          "division_seasons.fixtures_grid"  => $grid->id,
        }, {
        prefetch  => [
          "division_seasons",
          {
            "team_seasons" => {
              "team" => [{
                  "club" => "venue"
                },
                "home_night"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        order_by  => {
          -asc => [ qw( division_seasons.rank team_seasons.grid_position club.short_name team.name ) ]
        }
      });
    }
```

This returns the data as I would expect and I'm able to do the following in my Controller code to get back my resultset and iterate through the team_seasons:

```
    my $divisions = [ $c->model("DB::Division")->divisions_and_teams_in_season($current_season, $c->stash->{grid}) ];

    foreach my $division ( @{ $divisions } ) {
      $c->log->debug( $division->team_seasons->grid_positions_filled ); # This works because $division->team_seasons is a resultset object 
    }
```

However, in my template (having stashed `$divisions`), I'm unable to access the grid_positions_filled object because division.team_seaons gives me an arrayref of team resultsets in that division:

```
    [%
    # Loop through our divisions
    FOREACH division IN divisions;
      CALL c.log.debug(division.team_seasons); # The output of this is something like: ARRAY(0x6f8318c)
    END;
    -%]
```

The output I get for the same debug log in my controller is more like a list of resultset objects:

```
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6eea94c)
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6f01834)
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6ef5284)
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6efec9c)
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6ef4dc4)
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6faf0ac)
    TopTable::Model::DB::TeamSeason=HASH(0x6eefa04)
```

Hope all this makes sense!  Does anyone know how I can get the behaviour from the controller into the template so that I can access methods on the team_season ResultSet?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Looks like a scalar vs. list context issue. Try `team_seasons_rs` to force the return of a resultset in list context.

Comment: Sorry @nwellnhof, I'm not sure I follow - where should I be putting `team_seasons_rs`?  As I understand it, `team_seasons` refers to the relationship name between the two tables and `team_seasons_rs` is not a valid relationship name?

Comment: DBIC also creates a special version of a relationship accessor postfixed with `_rs`. See [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship#has_many).

Comment: Ahh, so I see, that's excellent thank you so much!  (If you post it as an answer I can accept it I think?  New to Stack Overflow (other than just lurking!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `team_seasons` accessor returns a resultset in scalar context, and an array of rows in list context. It seems that template toolkit code evaluates the accessor in list context.

As a work-around, DBIC installs a special accessor, postfixed with `_rs` that always returns a resultset regardless of context. So the following should work:

```
CALL c.log.debug(division.team_seasons_rs.grid_positions_filled);
```

This is documented under [`DBIx::Class::Relationship`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship#has_many).

Answer (score 2):

Try `$self->search_rs` rather than `$self->search`.  "This method does the same exact thing as search() except it will always return a resultset, even in list context."

[See the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082810/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#search_rs) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I thought it looked like it may work, but I still get the same thing:

`WHILE (division = divisions.next);
  CALL c.log.debug(division.team_seasons);
END;`
This still gives me: ARRAY(0x6e3a08c).

Comment: My guess is that it's still a context gotcha on the relationship (team_seasons).  You could try looking at http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Stash/Context.html  I have not personally used it, but it would allow you to force scalar context via something like `c.log.debug(division.team_seasons.scalar)`

Comment: The comment by @nwellnhof above which points out that "DBIC also creates a special version of a relationship accessor postfixed with _rs", is something I wasn't aware of and provides a much simpler solution than using a different template stash.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm told that scalar should also work - admittedly I've not tried it for the reason you just mentioned, but thank you very much for your help.